# Right way to pass NSArray of NSNumber as parameter in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, nsarray, afnetworking

I am trying to send in POST request AFNetworking this package:

```
NSDictionary*parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@719,@714, nil],@"rules", nil];

[manager POST:path parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        triedAuthorize = NO;

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    }];
```

And server returns error as if I made error in JSON

In this case server returns success:

```
NSDictionary*parameters = @{@"rules":@"[719,714]"}
```

and this is successful to

```
NSDictionary*parameters = @{@"rules":@"719,714"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this

Problem was not in array as parameter. I've added this and everything work:

```
manager.requestSerializer = [ALFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:719],[NSNumber numberWithInt:714],nil],@"rules", nil];
```

Use above will resolve your issue